# blurry image rendered

Tags: directx, rendering

I'm using Direct2D to render a PNG image using a ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget and then caling it's GetBitmap() function and rendering the image using ID2D1HwndRenderTarget::DrawBitmap().

Some of the images rendered this way are clear but others appear blurry. I did some research and followed a tutorial to make my application "DPI Aware" but it didn't help.

[image]

(sample with a blurry image on the left)

What could cause the rendered image to appear blurry? Has anyone experienced this issue before? What can I do about this?

Comment: How about a screenshot?

Comment: Here is the same PNG file, rendered blurry on the left and clear on the right: http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/9853/blurx.png

Comment: My eyes are not that great, but it doesn't look blurry to me.

Comment: @Jason Your image to imageshack is no longer valid. You probably want to reupload it to stack.imgur instead. (Image shack has started to remove old images and replace them by ads; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771 for more details).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m not exactly knowledgeable in Direct2D, but you're probably drawing your image on a half-pixel boundary, and you're getting pwned by antialiasing.

Try drawing the first image half a pixel to the bottom right, so instead of doing

```
Draw(something, x, y);
```

do something like

```
Draw(something, x + 0.5, y + 0.5);
```

Google "Direct2D half pixel" for information on how to do this.

Comment: Glad I could help.